# Android: Database Fields not populating through a loop

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I am currently trying to make a function to prepopulate fields and determine if they have been set up or not. I need to add a total of 46 entries into my database so I figured a for loop would come in handy:

```
public void prepopulate() {
        Locker setup = new Locker(this);
        for (int x = 46; x < 47; x++) {
            setup.open();
            String lockerNumber = "Locker" + x;
            setup.createLockerEntry(lockerNumber, 0);
            setup.close();
        }
```

I

Any ideas, maybe a for loop wont work?

Comment: you forgot to add getWritableDatabase() before inserting values.

Comment: I did I just edited the code, forgot to post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to add 46 entries the why are you using  `for (int x = 46; x < 47; x++)`. This will work only for one entry.

Just change you for loop like

```
 for (int x = 0; x < 46; x++) //or any appropriate condition
```

Comment: thank you, that make more sense, must have done some "sleep coding"